# Generating a unique primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server database that will contain many tables that all connect, each with a primary key. I have a `Dictionary` that keeps track of the the primary keys fields are for each table. My task is to extract data every day from attribute-centric XML files and insert them into a master database. Each XML file has the same schema. I'm doing this by using an `XMLReader` and importing the data into a `DataSet`.

I can't use an `AutoNumber` for the keys. Let's say yesterday's XML file produced a `DataTable` similar to the following, and it was imported into a database

```
-------------------------------------
| Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|-----------------------------------|
|  0  | dsfsfsd | sdfsrer | sdfsfsf |
|-----------------------------------|
|  1  | dertert | qweqweq | xczxsdf |
|-----------------------------------|
|  2  | prwersd | xzcsdfw | qwefkgs |
-------------------------------------
```

If today's XML file produces the following `DataTable`

```
-------------------------------------
| Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|-----------------------------------|
|  0  | sesdfsd | hjghjgh | edrgffb |
|-----------------------------------|
|  1  | wrwerwr | zxcxfsd | pijghjh |
|-----------------------------------|
|  2  | vcbcvbv | vbnvnbn | bnvfgnf |
-------------------------------------
```

Then when I go to import the new data into the database using `SqlBulkCopy`, then there will be duplicate keys. My solution to this is to use `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to generate unique keys. Theoretically, this should always create a unique key.

However, for some reason `DateTime.Now.Ticks` is not unique. For example, 5 records in a row might all have the key `635387859864435908`, and the next 7 records might have the key `635387859864592164`, even though I am generating that value at different times. I want to say that the cause of the problem is that my script is calling `DateTime.Now.Ticks` several times before it updates the time.

Can anyone else think of a better way to generate keys?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just use GUIDs?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Ticks` was not intended be unique.  The amount of work a processor can get done in a *tick* is actually quite a bit, as you found out.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I haven't heard of GUIDs. I'm looking into them now to see if this will solve the problem

Comment: [Wikipedia -  Assuming uniform probability for simplicity, the probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth as of 2014 owned 600 million GUIDs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Comment: Check out [Eric Lippert's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/guids/) three part article on GUIDs for more information.

Comment: Just a warning, depending on how many records you have there can be a perf issue if you use a GUID for a primary key AND have it as a clustered index (which is the default). I usually pick a different column or group of columns to cluster on when I've got a GUID PK.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  If you're using SQL 2012 or later, you can use a `SEQUENCE`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @DMason I need the key to be generated in the C# script because of the way the tables link together. It recursively makes its way down to the bottom level of an element, and links back to the parent by this key that is generated.

Comment: You can "generate" the key from C# by making the call to the db for the next sequence value.  (Presumably, you'd do this once for each xml parent.)  That should work, right?  But, again, this would only be available for SQL Server 2012 or later.  I still don't know what SQL Server version you're using.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012, but there is the possibility of having to use 2008 for certain clients. I also don't want to have to query the database that many times because I feel it would significantly slow down my program (30 distinct elements, each with there own set of 5-10 attributes. Each XML file has 300000-500000 lines). Creating a GUID works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the value of DateTime.Now is cached for a small amount of time for performance reasons. We do something similar to this and there are 2 possible options that we use:

1. Keep a list of numbers that you've used on the server you're on and increment if you can determine the number has already been used
2. Convert the field to a string and append a GUID or some other random identifier on the end of it. A GUID can be created with `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`

Obviously neither of these plans are going to make the risk of collision zero, but they can help in reducing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have huge amount of data and you need to have a unique key for each row just use [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following to get a unique id ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/5567)):

```
SELECT
CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(DAY, STR(YEAR(GETDATE()), 4) + '0101',
GETDATE() ) + 1,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC)) UniqueID
FROM supportContacts s
```

This would work if you only run the query once per day.  If you ran it more than once per day you would need to grab the seconds or something else ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/5586/1)):

```
SELECT CONCAT(CurrYear, CurrJulian, CurrSeconds, Row) AS UniqueID
FROM
(
  SELECT
  YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CurrYear, 
  DATEDIFF(DAY, STR(YEAR(GETDATE()), 4) + '0101', GETDATE() ) + 1 AS CurrJulian,  
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) AS Row,
  datediff(second, left(convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 126), 10), getdate()) AS CurrSeconds
  from supportContacts s
) AS m
```